# Deleting rows with multiple blank cells in that row using AutoFilter

Tags: vba, performance, excel, autofilter

We have an Excel file with over 550,000 rows, and my task is to "clean up" this worksheet.  This file contains all of the products that we get from different vendor and all the data that goes with it.

The specific task I am having trouble with is how to delete all of the rows in which column A AND Column B are both empty.

Using a MUCH smaller excel file, this can very easily be done using:

```
Dim j As Long, i As Long

j = Cells(Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row
For i = j To 1 Step -1
    If Cells(i, "A") = "" And Cells(i, "B") = "" Then
        Cells(i, "A").EntireRow.Delete
    End If
Next I
```

Unfortunately, this does not work due to the sheer size of the file.

Before this point, I successfully deleted all rows that have a blank cell in column C using the following code:

```
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.EnableEvents = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

Dim oldWs As Worksheet, newWs As Worksheet
Dim wsName As String, lastRow As Range

Set oldWs = Worksheets(2)
wsName = oldWs.Name

lastRow = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count

If lastRow.Rows.Count > 1 Then
    Set newWs = Sheets.Add(After:=oldWs)
    With lastRow
        .AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:="<>"
        .Copy
    End With
    With newWs.Cells
        .PasteSpecial xlPasteColumnWidths
        .PasteSpecial xlPasteAll
        .Cells(1, 1).Select
        .Cells(1, 1).Copy
    End With
    oldWs.Deletesheet
    newWs.Name = wsName
End If

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.EnableEvents = True
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
```

I have been looking around on how to use .AutoFilter on multiple columns, but nothing seems to be working properly.

Any method or ways to speed up the first mentioned process, to allow multiple Fields to be entered into .AutoFilter, or just any other way in general would be such a big help

p.s. I have looked at almost every related question/answer and could not find something that works for me, but I feel like I'm getting close

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this should help you to to *"delete all of the rows in which column A AND Column B are both empty"*

```
Option Explicit

Sub main()
    With Worksheets("Products") ' change "Products" to your actual sheet name
        With .Range("A1", .Cells(.Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp))
            .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="="
            .AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:="="
            MsgBox .Address
            If Application.WorksheetFunction.Subtotal(103, .Columns(3)) > 1 Then .Resize(.Rows.Count - 1).Offset(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Delete
        End With
        .AutoFilterMode = False
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Wow, it was really that simple.. Thank you so much!!

Comment: Couly you possible explain the line which contains the subtotal (103)?

Comment: You are welcome. It counts the number of visible (i.e. not filtered) cells in the specified range (in this case `.Columns(3)`, i.e. the third column of the referenced range)

Answer (score 0):

What's `N` for? you don't use it anywhere

```
Dim j As Long, i As Long

j = Cells(Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row
For i = j To 1 Step -1
       If Range("A" & i).Value = vbNullString And Range("B" & i).Value = vbNullString Then Rows(i).Delete
Next i
```

Should work fine. Bear in mind that 500,000 lines will take a while to process.

You can speed up the process by putting

```
With Application
    .ScreenUpdating = False
    .EnableEvents = False
    .DisplayAlerts = False
End With
```

At the start (and putting everything back to `True` at the end)

Comment: thank you for spotting that, I've been renaming some variables